# How to find all the grid points between two grid point in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have profile (function) in MatLab and now I want to find all the grid points between a point on the profile and on a source line (another line on top of my profile), so that I can check the value of my function at those grid points.

Basically I need to find the visibility angle (the angle which is visible from a point on my profile of the source).

Please help !

Thanks in advance

What I want to do is that given two grid points which can be joined by a straight line, I want to know the index of the grid points lying on that line. Somehow I need to know through which all grid points, the line passes throug

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please explain the problem better, and preferably post some code that illustrate what you have tried, and what your problem is? It's hard to help without it.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! What I want to do is that given two grid points which can be joined by a straight line, I want to know the index of the grid points lying on that line. Somehow I need to know through which all grid points, the line passes through.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm

Comment: @Patashu Thanks a lot, it was what I was actually searching for !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding all places on a grid that are in a straight line between two points simply requires you to use a line drawing algorithm, such as [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) .

In MatLab this can be implemented by using the function given here

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28190-bresenham-optimized-for-matlab/content/bresenham.m

Developed by Aaron Wetzler.